# Issue with Spring Data Neo4j RelationshipProperties not saving properly using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j

Neo4j Desktop: 4.4.0

Spring Boot: 3.1.0

Spring Boot Data Neo4j: 3.1.0

Spring Data Neo4j: 7.1

Neo4j Java Driver: 5.8.0

Neo4j Cypher Dsl: 2023.2.0

Java: 17

```
@Node
public NodeOne{
//class stuff

@Relationship(type="RELATED_TO", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
List<RelatedTo> relationships = new ArrayList<RelatedTo>();
}

@Node
public NodeTwo{
//class stuff
}

@RelationshipProperties
public RelatedTo{

    @RelationshipId
    private Long id;

    @TargetNode
    private NodeTwo nodeTwo;

    // getters & setters
```

When I run the code, I'll get the following nodes in Neo4j:

NodeOne
NodeTwo
RelatedTo

The relationships are not properly saving to showing Neo4j Browser or Bloom